# Why do the components of PCR mixture need to be added in a specific order?

Tags: molecular-biology, pcr

I have recently been told that the components of a PCR mixture need to be added in a specific order: primers, dNTP, and finally polymerase. May I know why this is the case?

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on what we do here. Please also note the [homework policy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework), which requires questions to contain evidence that the asker has attempted to answer the question for themselves. On that note; what do you know about those components and why might you add polymerase last (what does it do, and what could it do if you add it earlier?)?

Comment: you may be able to find your awnser here: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/79024/why-is-dna-polymerase-added-at-the-end-of-pcr-reaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymerase last: One reson is that pipetting conditions are vastly differing by person, I.e. a lot of people don't keep the reactions on ice. When no hot-start polymerase is used, pipetting it in too early in a room temp. reaction mix might lead to unintended reactions.